# How to refresh listview in fragment after asynctask finishes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-context

When application starts in the main activity is USNameFragment. This fragment starts Asynctask and after Asynctask completes, he sends back list of results to fragment thru interface. Fragment then gets back this list in onDataRetrieved() and then should display this list.

Hovewer after USNameFragment onCreate() the fragment listview is empty. But Toast in onDataRetrieved() says that there are 3 objects retrieved from Asynctask.

I did find a trick to show it, but its not as it should be working.
List items show in listview only after do configuration change, example change device orientation, but not when fragment is created.

What is wrong here? Thanks for suggestion.

Here is my interface to communicate between Fragment and AsyncTask:

```
public interface IActivityRef {

void onDataRetrieved(List<USDto> usDtos);
}
```

Here is my Fragment which implements IActivityRef interface:

```
public class USNameFragment extends Fragment
    implements IActivityRef {

private AsyncTask<String, Void, USResponse> usTask;
private WeakReference<IActivityRef> context;
private ListView listUSNames;
private List<String> usNames;

public USNameFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    usNames = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    this.context = new WeakReference<>((IActivityRef) this);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    context = null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);

    usTask = new USTask(this);
    usTask = usTask.execute("params");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_us_name, container, false);

    listUSNames = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listUS);
    listUSNames.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), R.layout.item_us_name, R.id.usName, usNames));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (usTask != null && usTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        usTask.cancel(true);
    }
    usTask = null;

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDataRetrieved(List<USDto> usDtos) {
    this.usNames = new USColumns().getUSNames(usDtos);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data retrieved! List size = " + usDtos.size(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

And here is the Asynctask:

```
public class USTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, USResponse> {

private WeakReference<IActivityRef> context;
private TwApiClient twApiClient;

public USTask(IActivityRef context) {

    this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected USResponse doInBackground(String... params) {

    // do http code here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(USResponse usResponse) {
    super.onPostExecute(usResponse);

    if(context != null && usResponse != null) {
        IActivityRef activity = context.get();
        activity.onDataRetrieved(usResponse.getUS());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

**EDIT**
Think the fragment layout is created before list is retrieved in onDataRetrieved(). Maybe should refresh listview some how?

**EDIT2**
Problem was with refreshing listview adapter and not with sending context from fragment to asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with not updating ListView adapter after asynctask finished in onDataRetrieved() in the fragment.

So the solution turned out to be so simple as that:

Add this field to USNameFragment:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
```

Then in onCreateView() initialize this adapter and assign it to listview:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_us_name, container, false);

    listUSNames = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listUS);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), R.layout.item_us_name, R.id.usName, usNames);
    listUSNames.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

And then in onDataRetrieved() reinitialize this adapter:

```
@Override
public void onDataRetrieved(List<USDto> usDtos) {
    this.usNames = new USColumns().getUSNames(usDtos);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), R.layout.item_us_name, R.id.usName, usNames);
    listUSNames.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Also moved start of asynctask from onCreate() to onAttach() in USNameFragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    this.context = new WeakReference<>((IActivityRef) this);
    usTask = new USTask(this);
    usTask = usTask.execute("params");
```

}

And thats it.